# Node js Use puppeteer synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, puppeteer

Hi i'm trying to use puppeteer synchronously but i'm getting an error when i try to access the click method on the page:

```
let _browser;
let _page;

    puppeteer
      .launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null })
      .then((browser) => (_browser = browser))
      .then((browser) => (_page = browser.newPage()))
      .then((page) => page.goto('https://instagram.com'))
      .then(() => _page)
      .then((page) =>  page.waitForTimeout(3000))
      .then((page) => page.click('button[class="aOOlW   HoLwm "]'))
      .then(() => _browser.close());
```

I get an error on button click (`.then((page) => page.click('button[class="aOOlW   HoLwm "]'))`):

> file:/index.js:38   .then((page) => page.click('button[class="aOOlW
> HoLwm "]'))
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')
> at file::/index.js:38:24

Is there a way to access the click method of **page** synchronously? Why am I getting that error?

Comment: What does this `page.waitForTimeout(3000)` returns ?

Comment: @CodeManiac return an object ->  [object Promise]

Comment: @CodeManiac if I reverse the order between waitForTimeout and click, and then waitForTimeout will be after the click, it will give the error on waitForTimeout, in the same way

Comment: In next `then` block you're doing `page.click`, which is not present so you end up in that error, make sure you pass page to next then block.

Comment: should i do `.then (() => _page)` again?

Comment: This isn't synchronous. Puppeteer is async-only. You'll need to pass the `page` object through the whole promise chain if you want to do it with `.then`, or always call `_page`, otherwise you're trying to call `page` methods on, say, the return value of `page.waitForSelector()` or whatever. It's much easier to use `async`/`await` as you'll see in almost every Puppeteer example.